# how to make one row of an UITableView become text editable?

Tags: iphone

I hope to display one row of UITableView with property

```
cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

if user touches/selects the row, it will display an UITextField for user to edit the text of this row.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator* shows a chevron on the table row, this indicates that another view will be activated, so isn't appropriate for an editable row.

> The cell has an accessory control shaped like a regular chevron. It is intended as a disclosure indicator. The control doesn't track touches.

What you might want to do instead is set the [accessoryView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on your [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to a [UITextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html).